# Executing mysqli_query works but it does not return exact row given in WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

The query executes  .. but let's say for example the user changed the value of $_GET['sub'] to get an id which is not in the database , lets say for example : 60 .
it should print "NOT FOUND" instead it prints found ! Why is that ?

```
 $main = new  MainClass();

 $subid = mysqli_real_escape_string($main->MsqlConRes,$_GET['sub']);

if (is_numeric($subid))
{
    $main->query = mysqli_query($main->MsqlConRes,"SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE id = ".$subid."") or die(mysqli_error());
    if ($main->query)
    {
        echo'Found';
    }
    else
        echo'Not Found !';
}
else
    $main->errors(404);
```

Comment: `user edited the $_GET['sub'] ` -> basically that meanss user editing pre existing record

Comment: i meant from the sub value from the URL ! 
exmpl : index.php?sub=id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `mysqli_num_row()`  in  `if`

```
if (mysqli_num_row($main->query)>0)
    {
        echo'Found';
    }
    else
        echo'Not Found !';
```

Since query is executing properly so  `if ($main->query)` will always be true

Comment: Thank you it worked !
that function  that  i was looking for !